# Moving a shapefile point 500 m west

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, shapefile

I am a novice to arcgis 10 so please forgive my ignorance.I have this 2000 survey points shapefile and I was told to , I guess is dislocate, generate new survey points, each new should be 500m west and 500m south from the original point. How can I do that in arcgis 10? I remember there use to be in a move button, but I canot find it now. Can you help me?

Answer (score 8):

You can do it with field calculator using Python parser:

Create a copy of your file

Open table, select shape field, switch to advanced mode type:

```
def pMove(shp):
 pM=arcpy.Point()
 p=shp.firstPoint
 pM.X=p.X-500
 pM.Y=p.Y-500
 return pM
```

in the box below type:

```
pMove(!Shape!)
```

This is good place to learn about field calculator http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s0000002m000000

Comment: +1, I love this solution.  I'm going to use this and incorporate the X and Y as parameters in the function to move it any desired amount.

Comment: Thank you @Fezter. Shifts are simple, sometimes you want to rotate them, have a look http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159631/splitting-all-polygon-features-in-a-shapefile-into-smaller-equal-width-polygons/159653#159653

Answer (score 7):

How precise do you need to be? Does it have to be exactly 500.0m South + 500.0 m West, or can you eyeball it?

If you can eyeball it, the easiest way is just to turn on **Editor mode**:

[image: Start Editing]

Then select all your points and drag them towards the southwest roughly 500.0*sqrt(2)=**707.1m**.

[image: Drag]

---

**Alternatively** if you want to move all points precisely 500.0m South and 500.0m West:

- Take an existing point, copy and paste it.
- Select the copied point and *right-click* > *Edit Vertices*, *right-click* > *Move*. Type in 500.0 by 500.0.

[image: Move Point]

This extra point will be used as an ***anchor point***. Select all your points and, with your mouse on the original point, drag it and ***Snap*** it to the anchor point.

[image: Anchor]

Snapping behavior is controlled by a separate toolbar.

[image: Snapping]

You can delete the extraneous anchor point when you're done. This should get you pretty precise.