# Splitting all polygon features in a shapefile into smaller equal width polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, splitting, vector-grid, parcel

I have a shapefile of thousands of polygon features, that i would like to break up into smaller pieces (i.e. break a square into 8 equal pieces). I have read all over these boards for the right solution and haven't found one yet unfortunately. I've tried parcel editor but that only allows you to manually edit one feature at a time, and I've tried fishnet but that doesn't run through each individual feature it just processes across the entire extent of the shapefile. I have the full license for ArcGIS so all options are game. Ultimately I would like to be able to split this initial shapefile of features into a specified amount of equal width slots that each would be their own feature in the resulting shapefile.

Any thoughts?

Comment: if you just need squares from the original polygon you can use [Create Fishnet](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//00170000002q000000)

Comment: Well my shapefile of polygons are discontinuous so there will be blank space between the different polygons.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem you are having with the fishnet grid. Is there any reason you can't just create a fishnet and clip and/or spatial join it to your polygons?

Comment: @BruceDoh I think the problem with using a fishnet is that because the features to be cut are discontinuous, you may not get equal pieces in all features.

Comment: Alec, is the width of a slot dependent on the size of the feature? That is, if a feature is 8 units wide, the new features would be 1 unit wide, while in a feature 16 units wide, the new features would be 2 units wide?

Answer (score 6):

Attach script

```py
import arcpy, traceback, os, sys, math
from math import radians,sin,cos
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True
inFC=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
outFolder=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
rectangle=r'in_memory\rectangle'
tempf=r'd:\scratch\many.shp'
def showPyMessage():
    arcpy.AddMessage(str(time.ctime()) + " - " + message)
def ShapeMake(pGon,angle):
    ar=arcpy.Array()
    a=radians(angle)
    part=pGon.getPart(0)
    for p in part:
        x,y=p.X,p.Y
        xN=cos(a)*x+sin(a)*y
        yN=-sin(a)*x+cos(a)*y
        pN=arcpy.Point(xN,yN)
        ar.add(pN)
    pgonRotated=arcpy.Polygon(ar)
    return pgonRotated

try:
    arcpy.MinimumBoundingGeometry_management(inFC,rectangle,
                                             "RECTANGLE_BY_WIDTH", "NONE", "", "MBG_FIELDS")
    m,n=0,0
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(rectangle, ("SHAPE@","MBG_Orientation")) as rows:
        for row in rows:
            shp,angle = row
            onside=ShapeMake(shp,-angle)
            extent=onside.extent
            origPoint='%s %s' %(extent.XMin,extent.YMin)
            yPoint='%s %s' %(extent.XMin,extent.YMax)
            endPoint='%s %s' %(extent.XMax,extent.YMax)
            if extent.width>extent.height:nRows,nCols=1,8
            else:nRows,nCols=8,1
            arcpy.CreateFishnet_management(tempf, origPoint,yPoint,
                                           "0", "0", nRows, nCols,endPoint,
                                           "NO_LABELS", "", "POLYGON")
            arcpy.AddField_management(tempf, "Rotation", "DOUBLE")
            arcpy.AddField_management(tempf, "Label", "Text", 25)
            m+=1
            with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(tempf, ["SHAPE@","Rotation","Label"]) as rows:
                for row in rows:
                    shp = row[0]
                    rollBack=ShapeMake(shp,angle)
                    row[0]=rollBack
                    row[1]=angle
                    m+=1
                    row[2]=str(m).zfill(8)
                    rows.updateRow(row)
            n+=1
            arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(tempf, '%s%sfnet_%s'%(outFolder,os.sep,str(n).zfill(4)))
except:
    message = "\n*** PYTHON ERRORS *** "; showPyMessage()
    message = "Python Traceback Info: " + traceback.format_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])[0]; showPyMessage()
    message = "Python Error Info: " +  str(sys.exc_type)+ ": " + str(sys.exc_value) + "\n"; showPyMessage()
```

to tool:

[image]

Input feature layer:

[image]

Merge all shapefiles from Output Folder into single feature class shown below:

[image]