# How to create a square polygon or buffer with quadrants in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon

I have 32 points than I need to create a 2 mile square polygon around, and break each polygon into 4 quadrants. I've tried a few things, including creating an MBR(Minimum Bounding Rectangle) around a standard buffer, but those don't output perfect squares for some reason, which doesn't necessarily totally matter, but I hit a wall when I try to break the square polygons into quadrants.

I'm using the NAD 1983 UTM Zone 12N coordinate system for the map. The Geodatabase for my data is GCS_North_American_1983. I'm using ArcGIS 10.3.1

Here's an example of what I generally need.
[image: example]

Comment: What is an MBR?

Comment: Please **edit** your question to specify the version of ArcGIS, the coordinate system of the data, and the coordinate system of the map canvas.  If your preferred programming interface is not Python, you should specify that as well.

Comment: minimum bounding rectangle, sorry!  added to the question

Comment: You can use Fishnet for this type of operation. Although, you'll need to extract the coords from the plot center and manipulate this (i.e. subtract x/y coords) to form the fishnet origin. All of this can be accomplished with Python and arcpy.

Comment: In what coordinate system are the points?  Generating a square or set of squares in a *projected* coordinate system should be simple. Please provide the code/procedure that came closest to what you want.

Comment: You can do it using my script http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159631/splitting-all-polygon-features-in-a-shapefile-into-smaller-equal-width-polygons/159653#159653 Let me know if you are able to tweak it, if noy I'll do it

Comment: @FelixIP I'm woefully inadequate when it comes to scripting, so I'm not sure I'll be able to tweak this to suit my needs, at least not any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the way the map on your screen is projected, the resulting shape may not look perfectly square. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection).

Difficult work-around would be to split your polygon into lines, get the midpoints of the lines, draw lines between them, merge the result into a polygon, and then use that to clip the original square. But there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Use your buffers as first parameter for script:

[image]

[image]

Use empty folder as second parameter for script. Run script. Merge all shapefiles in input folder to get this:

[image]

Script:

```
import arcpy, traceback, os, sys
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True
inFC=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
outFolder=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

tempf=r'in_memory\many'

def showPyMessage():
    arcpy.AddMessage(str(time.ctime()) + " - " + message)

try:
    m,n=0,0
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inFC, "SHAPE@") as rows:
        for row in rows:
            shp = row[0]
            extent=shp.extent
            origPoint='%s %s' %(extent.XMin,extent.YMin)
            yPoint='%s %s' %(extent.XMin,extent.YMax)
            endPoint='%s %s' %(extent.XMax,extent.YMax)

            nRows,nCols=2,2

            arcpy.CreateFishnet_management(tempf, origPoint,yPoint,
                                           "0", "0", nRows, nCols,endPoint,
                                           "NO_LABELS", "", "POLYGON")
            arcpy.AddField_management(tempf, "Label", "Text", 25)
            m+=1
            arcpy.AddMessage(m)
            with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(tempf, ("SHAPE@","Label")) as rows:
                for row in rows:
                    m+=1
                    row[1]=str(m).zfill(8)
                    rows.updateRow(row)
            n+=1
            arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(tempf, '%s%sfnet_%s'%(outFolder,os.sep,str(n).zfill(4)))
except:
    message = "\n*** PYTHON ERRORS *** "; showPyMessage()
    message = "Python Traceback Info: " + traceback.format_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])[0]; showPyMessage()
    message = "Python Error Info: " +  str(sys.exc_type)+ ": " + str(sys.exc_value) + "\n"; showPyMessage()
```

Please note dimensions could be slightly out, because buffer is not exactly circle, just a collection of connected points