# Dividing an irregular polygon into sub-regions

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon

I am trying to divide an irregular polygon into equal widths and am having trouble understanding the proper tool to use. I am in possession of ArcGIS and am aware that the Parcel Editor is the closest function to accomplish this task, but I am not actually able to edit said polygon - any ideas? I am also aware that I could divide the regions manually with the cut polygons tool, but I was looking for something more automatic.

Below is my goal, mainly to divide the regions into approximately an equal width of *w*.
[image]

Comment: You need to edit your question with an image of what you want.

Comment: Are you working with parcels (i.e. a Parcel Fabric)? If not, the Parcel Editor would be an odd choice.

Comment: I posted script here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159631/splitting-all-polygon-features-in-a-shapefile-into-smaller-equal-width-polygons/159653#159653 a while ago

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cut up your polygon into squares, one thing you could try is:

1. get minimum bounding geometry (envelope, something with a rectangular/square result)
2. create grid from minimum bounding geometry (check out Ian Broad's custom grid tool http://ianbroad.com/creating-quarter-quarter-section-grid-python/)
3. convert your polygon to line
4. merge polygon line with custom grid
5. convert merged lines to polygons
6. select split polygons by locations having their centroid in input polygon

The result will be a polygon cut into squares/rectangles, except for the irregular parts that you can identify by getting the ratio of split polygon calculated area divided by the calculated area of the split polygon's minimum bounding geometry.

EDIT:
This methodology could still work for what you're trying to do; for the minimum bounding geometry, use rectangle by area, and using Ian Broad's tool just put in a value for the horizontal divisions and 0 for vertical divisions.

Edit:
Here's my split polygon using this methodology. The green line is the minimum bounding geometry using rectangle by area.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might try the Editor, Copy Parallel tool to create lines the same distance apart. This would be a Polyline feature class. The Advanced Editing Tool bar has Split Polygon tool. First, Select the lines overlapping your polygon, then execute the tool. Your Polygon will be cut by each line. The lines need to extend beyond the edges of your polygon.