# Splitting regular polygons into same-height segments

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, splitting

I have vector layer which looks like this:[image]

It is result of raster classification, vectorization and finally Minimum Bounding Box Geometry. What I need is, that maximum "height" of one polygon is for example 20 cm. It means the small rectangles stay the same as they are smaller than this threshold, but the "long ones" divide into several smaller polygons. After I will create centroids and count number of these polygons in one row, so first I need to have the small polygon segments.

Comment: What does "height" mean in this context for you?

Comment: Have you had a look at this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321021/splitting-polygon-into-equal-area-polygons-in-qgis-3#:~:text=There%20is%20a%20plugin%20in,tool%20to%20perform%20that%20task.

Comment: The longer side of the rectangle. I mean when the polygon has 2 x 0.5 m, then I want to split it into 10 polygons with size 0.2 x 0.5 m.

Comment: But then the "long side" is 0.5 m long?

Comment: Yes, I have looked at that question but the problem is that my layer contains of thousands of these small polygons, so drawing points inside of each polygon or setting exact number of split is not good way for me. If there would be only small amount of polygons I would do it manually as well. Actually the numbers I gave you were just example, in reality I would like to create near-square shaped segments, if you understand. I just need  IF condition - if the longer side of rectangle is more than 20 cm, than divide it into several polygon with size 20 cm, the second dimension stays the same.

Comment: Can be done with little modification of this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159631/splitting-all-polygon-features-in-a-shapefile-into-smaller-equal-width-polygons/159653#159653

Comment: I guess you can solve this specific problem by only using a script. Which software do you use? QGIS or ArcGIS. I have a kind of solution using PyQGIS script if you prefer.

Comment: I can use both QGIS and ArcMap.