# R spTransform() in lidR - error: non quantizable value

Tags: coordinate-system, r, lidr

I am trying to reproject a las file in `lidR` ([doawnload file here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmMT5E-2wBxLhjaY_y3ESn5gI2jL?e=ifffYC)) from `epsg:2232` to `epsg:32613`, and get the following error message after about 3 seconds of processing:

```r
las <- readLAS("LD31201353.las")
projection(las) <- sp::CRS("EPSG:2232")
spTransform(las, CRSobj = "+init=epsg:32613")
#> Error in fast_quantization(X, scalex, offsetx) : 
#>  Non quantizable value outside the range of representable values of type 'int'
```

Has anyone encountered this, and might you have suggestions for a fix (or what I'm doing wrong)?

The las file natively does not have its 'WKT OGC COORDINATE SYSTEM' field or  projargs slot populated, but I get the error with and without assigning them.

```r
las@header
#> File signature:           LASF 
#> File source ID:           0 
#> Global encoding:
#>  - GPS Time Type: Standard GPS Time 
#>  - Synthetic Return Numbers: no 
#>  - Well Know Text: CRS is WKT 
#>  - Aggregate Model: false 
#> Project ID - GUID:        00000001-0012-07e3-0000-000000000000 
#> Version:                  1.4
#> System identifier:        Merrick 
#> Generating software:      MARS 
#> File creation d/y:        188/2018
#> header size:              375 
#> Offset to point data:     377 
#> Num. var. length record:  0 
#> Point data format:        6 
#> Point data record length: 30 
#> Num. of point records:    1965664 
#> Num. of points by return: 1634171 285040 42901 3469 82 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
#> Scale factor X Y Z:       0.001 0.001 0.001 
#> Offset X Y Z:             3122231 1354500 11639 
#> min X Y Z:                3121464 1353000 11008.84 
#> max X Y Z:                3123000 1356000 11782.48 
#> Variable length records: 
#>    Variable length record 1 of 1 
#>        Description: WKT Information 
#>        WKT OGC COORDINATE SYSTEM: PROJCRS["NAD83 / Colorado Central (ftUS)",
#>     BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83",
#>    [...] (truncated)
```

Comment: Anyway you can share your data or a subset of it that exhibits this problem? Or can you show your complete workflow as well as summary output and plots of your `las` object? What package are you using for LAS objects?

Comment: @Spacedman - sorry, new to this, I don't see an upload file option.  11MB is the size of a 5x5m sample, anyway.

Comment: @Kahdir Sahbaz - thank you for the formatting!

Comment: @Spacedman:  Win 10 Home, rgdal_1.5-21, lidR_3.1.1, raster_3.4-5, sp_1.4-5

Comment: You'll need a third-party to share data files - dropbox, onedrive, box, or some other file storage. I've added "lidr" to the tags since some people have searches triggered on tags.

Comment: Here's a link to a sample file (56MB):  https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmMT5E-2wBxLhjaY_y3ESn5gI2jL?e=ifffYC.  I'll send a link to my script once another process I have running finishes.  In the meantime, feel free to dig into this file and see what process works for you to re-project it to epsg:32613.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, first, we need a reproducible example

```r
library(lidR)
data = data.frame(X = c(3176138, 3173598),Y = c(1434968, 1432401), Z = 0)
header = rlas::header_create(data)
header[["X offset"]] = 3172500
header[["Y offset"]] = 1432500
header[["X scale factor"]] = 0.001
header[["Y scale factor"]] = 0.001
las = LAS(data, header)
projection(las) = 2232

spTransform(las, CRSobj = "+init=epsg:32613")
#> Error in fast_quantization(X, scalex, offsetx) : 
#>  Non quantizable value outside the range of representable values of type 'int'
```

The problem comes from the fact that in a las file, coordinates are stored as integers. Because in `lidR`, `LAS` object are strictly (as far as possible) compliant to ASPRS specification of the LAS format it sometimes add a layer of complexity and triggers some error difficult to understand.

I already provided a comprehensive explanation of the LAS format and the importance of the scale and offset factors [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/360253/103469)

> In a las file coordinates are stored as integers with a scale factor
> and an offset to compute back decimal positioning. For example, a X
> coordinate might be 123456 with a scale factor 0.01 and offset of
> 100000 for an actual coordinate of 123456*0.01+100000 = 101234.56. The
> scale factor is the accuracy of your point (0.01 is a centimeter
> accuracy if the units are meters) and the offset enable memory and
> accuracy storage optimizations. This is the meaning of scale and
> offset.

In your case the scale factors are 0.001 and offsets are 3172500 and 1432500. When re-projecting from 2232 to 326013 the new coordinates range in [509611.1, 510389.3, 4318892, 4319670]

```r
spTransform(as.spatial(las), CRSobj = "+init=epsg:32613")
#> class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
#> features    : 2 
#> extent      : 509611.1, 510389.3, 4318892, 4319670  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs         : +proj=utm +zone=13 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#> variables   : 1
#> names       : Z 
#> min values  : 0
```

The problem is that new scale and offset factors are unknown, thus lidR re-use the old ones to quantize the value. Let do the math for Y

(4319670- 1432500)/0.001 = 2886392000

which is more than 2^31 and thus cannot be stored as integer with a scale factor of 0.001 and an offset of 1432500.

Now we understand the problem there is no solution because there is a bug in the function. The offsets are actually expected to be recomputed in `spTransform` but are not. This will be fixed in `lidR v3.1.2` (already fixed on [github](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR)).

In addition, for consistency across multiple tiles is is possible to set the offsets manually (in v >= 3.1.2)

```r
spTransform(las, CRSobj = "+init=epsg:32613", xoffset = 509600, yoffset = 4319600)
```