# Shrinking coordinates of LAS file to fit in [0,1] using lidR

Tags: lidr

I normalised a LAS file's coordinates so that XYZ all range between 0 and 1.

```r
Shift_Vox_X_ALS <- min(LAS_Vox_Test@data$X) 
Shift_Vox_Y_ALS <- min(LAS_Vox_Test@data$Y)
Shift_Vox_Z_ALS <- min(LAS_Vox_Test@data$Z)
              
LAS_Vox_Test@data$X <- LAS_Vox_Test@data$X - Shift_Vox_X_ALS
LAS_Vox_Test@data$Y <- LAS_Vox_Test@data$Y - Shift_Vox_Y_ALS
LAS_Vox_Test@data$Z <- LAS_Vox_Test@data$Z - Shift_Vox_Z_ALS
              
Shift_Vox_N_X_ALS <- max(LAS_Vox_Test@data$X)
Shift_Vox_N_Y_ALS <- max(LAS_Vox_Test@data$Y)
Shift_Vox_N_Z_ALS <- max(LAS_Vox_Test@data$Z)
              
LAS_Vox_Test@data$X <- LAS_Vox_Test@data$X/Shift_Vox_N_X_ALS
LAS_Vox_Test@data$Y <- LAS_Vox_Test@data$Y/Shift_Vox_N_Y_ALS
LAS_Vox_Test@data$Z <- LAS_Vox_Test@data$Z/Shift_Vox_N_Z_ALS
```

After normalising the coordinates, although `range(LAS_Vox_N@data$X)` is:

```
[1] 0 1    # same for Y and Z
```

the LAS extent is still:

```
extent : 372179.5, 372194.5, 5828865.5, 5828880.5 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

But typing gives:

```r
extent(LAS_Vox_N)
#> class      : Extent 
#> xmin       : 0 
#> xmax       : 1 
#> ymin       : 0 
#> ymax       : 1
```

I am not sure whether above behaviour is the reason why a saved las file (using `writeLAS()`) that is later opened (using `readLAS()`) produces erroneous y coordinates:

```
extent : 0, 1, 3681381.352, 3681381.352 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

```r
writeLAS(LAS_Vox_Test, paste(Folder_AU_VOX_LAS_TYPE[AU],"/LAS_Vox_Test2_Norm.laz", sep="")) 
LAS_OpenTest <- readLAS(paste(Folder_AU_VOX_LAS_TYPE[AU],"/LAS_Vox_Test2_Norm.laz", sep=""), select = "xyzp0")
```

Am I normalizing the coordinates  correctly so that all XYZ values are between 0 and 1? Obviously this removes the geographic position of the point cloud, which is what I need to do for this exercise. Is this allowed using LAS files in lidR?

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the coordinates by hand like that easily without messing-up your `LAS` object. `LAS` objects are designed to be as close as possible to the [las specification](http://www.asprs.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/LAS_1_4_r15.pdf) which imply that it is hard to touch a `LAS` object without understanding the specifications.

First you need to understand that numbers are stored in a LAS file as integers using a **scale factor** and an **offset**. Basically the scale factor is the accuracy of the positioning. 0.01 means a centimetre accuracy, 0.001 is millimetre (or 0.001 feet if coordinates are in feet). I already wrote a [comprehensive answer on this topic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/360247/rescaling-and-reoffsetting-a-point-cloud-with-lidr/360253#360253).

That being said, let do some math. Let say you have a point cloud 1000 x 1000 m with an accuracy of 0.01 i.e. centimetre accuracy (do the math with your own numbers). You want to shrink that in [0,1] so you want to scale your point-cloud to 1/1000<sup>th</sup>. With an accuracy of 0.01 your points will no longer be distinct. For example a point at X = 12345.12 m will be at e.g. X = 0.25 and a point 10 m farther at X = 12355.00 m will also be at X = 0.25. You need to change your accuracy if you want to write that in a LAS file. With an accuracy of 0.00001 the previous example may become X = 0.25123 and X = 0.25134 so the two points are now distinct.

If your point-cloud has an accuracy of 0.01 and you want to shrink to 1/1000<sup>th</sup> preserving the same relative accuracy you need an accuracy of 0.01/1000 = 0.00001.

So first you must start by doing the math for your point cloud and modify the header of the LAS object consequently. Here I'm using a 250 x 250 point-cloud with a scale factor of 0.01 on XYZ. To preserve the accuracy I need a scale factor of 0.01/250 = 4/100000. So, 10<sup>-5</sup> is ok. For Z 10<sup>-4</sup> is enough but we can use 10<sup>-5</sup> to be consistent.

```r
library(lidR)
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
las = readLAS(LASfile)

las@header@PHB[["X scale factor"]] <- 1e-5
las@header@PHB[["Y scale factor"]] <- 1e-5
las@header@PHB[["Z scale factor"]] <- 1e-5
las@header@PHB[["X offset"]] <- 0
las@header@PHB[["Y offset"]] <- 0
las@header@PHB[["Z offset"]] <- 0
```

Then I retrieve the bounding box. You can also use `min(las$X)` and so on if you want.

```r
xmin <- las@header@PHB[["Min X"]]
ymin <- las@header@PHB[["Min Y"]]
zmin <- las@header@PHB[["Min Z"]]
xmax <- las@header@PHB[["Max X"]]
ymax <- las@header@PHB[["Max Y"]]
zmax <- las@header@PHB[["Max Z"]]
```

Then I scale the point cloud. Pretty much like you did but you must avoid using `las@data$X` and use `las$X` instead. Using `las@data$` you are accessing the data directly. With `las$` your are using the `$` operator defined for `LAS` objects. And this operator is overloaded so it validates and fixes the input to be compliant with the LAS specification and updates automatically what must be updated. In short it ensures your object is valid with respect to the information in the header (we updated the header to fit our need) and warns you otherwise. See also `?las_utilities`.

```r
las$X <- (las$X - xmin)/(xmax - xmin)
las$Y <- (las$Y - ymin)/(ymax - ymin)
las$Z <- (las$Z - zmin)/(zmax - zmin)
```

Lastly I clear the CRS both erasing the `proj4string` and cleaning the header.

```r
projection(las) <- CRS()
las@header@VLR <- list()
```

Now we can check if everything is good.

```r
las
#> class        : LAS (v1.2 format 1)
#> memory       : 6.2 Mb 
#> extent       : 0, 1, 0, 1 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref.  : NA 
#> area         : 0.9996136 units²
#> points       : 81.6 thousand points
#> density      : 81621.54 points/units²
```

```r
las_check(las)
#> 
#>  Checking the data
#>   - Checking coordinates... ✓
#>   - Checking coordinates type... ✓
#>   - Checking coordinates range... ✓
#>   - Checking coordinates quantization... ✓
#>   - Checking attributes type... ✓
#>   - Checking ReturnNumber validity... ✓
#>   - Checking NumberOfReturns validity... ✓
#>   - Checking ReturnNumber vs. NumberOfReturns... ✓
#>   - Checking RGB validity... ✓
#>   - Checking absence of NAs... ✓
#>   - Checking duplicated points... ✓
#>   - Checking degenerated ground points... ✓
#>   - Checking attribute population...
#>    ⚠ 'PointSourceID' attribute is not populated.
#>    ⚠ 'EdgeOfFlightline' attribute is not populated.
#>   - Checking gpstime incoherances ✓
#>   - Checking flag attributes... ✓
#>   - Checking user data attribute... ✓
#>  Checking the header
#>   - Checking header completeness... ✓
#>   - Checking scale factor validity... ✓
#>   - Checking point data format ID validity... ✓
#>   - Checking extra bytes attributes validity... ✓
#>   - Checking the bounding box validity... ✓
#>   - Checking coordinate reference sytem... ✓
#>  Checking header vs data adequacy
#>   - Checking attributes vs. point format... ✓
#>   - Checking header bbox vs. actual content... ✓
#>   - Checking header number of points vs. actual content... ✓
#>   - Checking header return number vs. actual content... ✓
#>  Checking preprocessing already done 
#>   - Checking ground classification... yes
#>   - Checking normalization... yes
#>   - Checking negative outliers... ✓
#>   - Checking flightline classification... no
```

```r
extent(las)
#> class      : Extent 
#> xmin       : 0 
#> xmax       : 1 
#> ymin       : 0 
#> ymax       : 1
```

```r
plot(las, axis = T, clear_artifacts = F)
```

[image: screenshoot]