# Generating Parallel/offset points from Point location using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I am having a hard time explaining this so picture that I have a table with Lat Long and 3 additional values (X, Y, Z). What I want to do is plot the XY points and if additional Values are set as True, then generate a point Parallel to it or at an offset distance of 2.5 Meters for X, 5 meters for Y, and 7.5 Meters for Z. Here's a representation of the same.

| Point Name | Value X | Value Y | Value Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | True | True | True |
| B | True | True | True |
| C | True | True | False |
| D | True | False | False |

[image]

I can manually create this for 10-15 points but I have 1000+. So far I have tried https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/generate-points-along-lines.htm but that didn't help.

Comment: Arcpy with da.UpdateCursor , some if else and `SHAPE@X`/`SHAPE@Y` tokens. Project you points to a projected coordinate system first so the units are in meters

Comment: From your current tags and the documentation link I’ll assume you’re wanting to ask about ArcGIS Pro so that we can get this question re-opened.

Comment: In what way did the generate points along lines not help? You could create your base line, then use the copy parallel tool to duplicate your lines, generate points along them then retrospective delete out the False, thats one way to go.

Comment: See if this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201867/create-a-line-perpendicular-to-an-existing-line-in-arcgis/201871#201871 or this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159206/moving-a-shapefile-point-500-m-west/159300#159300 helps your case.